# Get private photos using flickrj-android

Tags: android, private, flickr, photos, flickrj

I am using the open source library: https://code.google.com/p/flickrj-android/ and there is an example how do I get photos from flickr. Main problem is that I get only public photos. How can I manage getting private streams/photos?
Did anyone managed to get private streams?

Answer (score 1):

With Flickrj-android you'd want to use this method:

```
 Flickr flickr = new Flickr(API_KEY,SHARED_SECRET,new REST());
    Set<String> extras = new HashSet();

    // A set of extra info we want Flickr to give back. Go to the API page to see the other size options available.
    extras.add("url_o");
    extras.add("original_format");

    //A request for a list of the photos in a set. The first zero is the privacy filter,
    // the second is the Pages, and the third is the Per-Page (see the Flickr API)

    PhotoList<Photo> photoList = flickr.getPhotosetsInterface().getPhotos(PHOTOSET_ID, extras, 0, 0, 0);


    //We'll use the direct URL to the original size of the photo in order to download it. Remember: you want to make as few requests from flickr as possible!

    for(Photo photo : photoList){
        //You can also get other sizes. Just ask for the info in the first request.
        URL url = new URL(photo.getOriginalSize().getSource());



        InputStream is = url.openStream();
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(PATH_OF_FOLDER + photo.getTitle() + "." +  photo.getOriginalFormat());

        byte[] b = new byte[2048];
        int length;

        while ((length = is.read(b)) != -1) {
            os.write(b, 0, length);
        }

        is.close();
        os.close();
    }
```

Use this method for a single-photo inputstream.

```
    InputStream inputStream = flickr.getPhotosInterface().getImageAsStream(flickr.getPhotosInterface().getPhoto(PHOTO_ID), Size.ORIGINAL);
```

Comment: Thanks, it works but... I have an issue: how do I access my client photos not mine? I used he's API_KEY+SHARED_SECRET, but I only get my photos. (when the authorization is done for the first time, it asks for my flickr credentials)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with Java and that framework but will try to help.
I found next method name in that framework:

```
public class PeopleInterface {
public static final String METHOD_GET_PHOTOS = "flickr.people.getPhotos";


/**
     * Returns photos from the given user's photostream. Only photos visible the
     * calling user will be returned. this method must be authenticated.
     *
     * @param userId
     * @param extras
     * @param perpage
     * @param page
     * @return
     * @throws IOException
     * @throws FlickrException
     * @throws JSONException
     */
    public PhotoList getPhotos(String userId, Set<String> extras, int perPage,
            int page)
```

From Flick API docs I found next:

> **flickr.people.getPhotos**   Return photos from the given user's photostream. Only photos visible to the calling user will be returned.
>   This method must be authenticated; to return public photos for a user,
>   use flickr.people.getPublicPhotos.

So, it mean that you **must** be authenticated with 'read' permissions to get your private pohotos (your account).
You can also get private photos of some users only in case if you are contact/friend of that user.